# Prevent sticky footer from moving up when scrolling up in Android Chrome browser

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, css-position, sticky-footer

I am developing a mobile website with `angular-material` which uses a fixed footer on the page. The footer is always present and fixed at the bottom. It all works well. However, when I scroll the page and the browser address bar hides, the body height changes as well. The result is that the fixed footer moves up too.

This is the CSS of the footer is as follows:

```
.mobile-ui .footer-mobile{
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 3;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Is there any possibility that the footer will stay fixed?
I would prefer not forcing the address bar to hide or stay fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way of fixing this. Android removes the adress bar and chrome automaticly resizes the body height. Position fixed will always place the footer at the bottom of the page.

Cause the behaviour is from the browser it self and not from the website you can't add a script or css feature to it.

Comment: position: absolute is the only fix i found.position:  Fixed is buggy in Android Browsers

Comment: is this still the case with position fixed? I am also struggeling with this issue.